# Magic number as default method parameter value

Tags: javascript, eslint

Eslint throws a warning when using a magic number as a default value in a method parameter. For example:

```
class Foo extends Component() {
    function bar(someVal = 3) { 
        //...
    }
```

So how does one get around that?

Comment: You could just change the rule,. in `.eslintrc`  Or temporally disable.  Sometimes constants make sense, using them here for a default value just seems silly.

Comment: @Keith There's no rule to only disable for method parameters no?

Comment: Not that I can tell, if you like the `no-magic-number` everywhere else, then the `// eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers`,  personally I just have that rule turned off, I know when I need to use a Constant.

Comment: @Keith Yeah I hear you. If it were up to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the default value beforehand, so as to (hopefully) make it more clear what the number represents:

```
const defaultSomeVal = 3;
class Foo extends Component {
  bar(someVal = defaultSomeVal) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If you have many of these, you might consider using an object instead of many standalone variables.

Comment: Would it make sense capitalizing these types of constants? I.e `DEFAULT_SOME_VAL`

Comment: Sure, that's a common enough convention you can follow if you want.